# Evaluate the limit of $\int\dots\int_{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2 \leq r^2} f(x_1) f(x_2)\dots f(x_n) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \dots \, dx_n$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The following question is taken from [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxudHVtYXRoY29tcGV0aXRpb25zfGd4OmRkYjVjODk3YmM4OGU2NA) problem $2.5:$

> **Exercise $2.5:$** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ and 
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = 1.$$
>   For $r\geq0,$ let 
>   $$I_n(x) = \int\dots\int_{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2 \leq r^2} f(x_1) f(x_2)\dots f(x_n) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \dots \, dx_n.$$
>   Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n(x)$ for a fixed $r.$

The answer given is $0.$ I think I need to use $n$-dimensional spherical substitution to reduce the problem over an $n$-dimension sphere.

However, I have no idea how to use it. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: first step: have you looked up the formulas for $n$-dimensional spherical substitution and looked at the examples?

Comment: A short answer is that $$I_n(r)=P(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2\leqslant r^2)$$ where $(X_k)$ is i.i.d. with PDF $f$ hence, say by the weak law of large numbers, $$I_n(r)\to0$$ The continuity of $f$ is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ satisfies definition for probability density function. So the problem can be reformulated as given $X_i \overset{iid}{\sim} X$, 
\begin{align*}
I_n &= E[I(X_1^2+\dotsb, X_n^2 \le r^2) ]\\
&= P(X_1^2+\dotsb, X_n^2 \le r^2)\\
&= P(nX^2 \le r^2)\\
&= P(X^2 \le \frac{r^2}{n})\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n &= P(X^2 \le 0)\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
The last few lines are a bit hand wavy, but I hope this helps.

Comment: The identity $$P(X_1^2+\dotsb, X_n^2 \le r^2)= P(nX^2 \le r^2)$$ is of course quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: More generally, suppose $f$ is continuous and nonnegative on $[-1,1],$ with $f\le M$ there. Then $I_n$ is bounded above by $M^n$ times the $n$-dimensional volume of $B(0,r).$ That volume is $r^n$ times the $n$-dimensional volume of $B(0,1).$ So everything depends on finding a good estimate of $V_n(B(0,1)).$

Comment: Why the downvote?